# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll' #001

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributes

```
import bs4 as bs
import pickle
import requests

def find_and_save_CSI_300():
response=requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSI_300_Index')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
table = soup.find('tadle',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
tickers = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:

  

ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
    ticker = ticker[:6]
    tickers.append(ticker)
    
with open("CSI_tickers.pickle","Wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(tickers,f)
print(tickers)
return tickers

find_and_save_CSI_300()
```

I'm having an issue with using the .findAll attribute. when I run the code below, it says object has no attribute findAll.

Comment: It says `NoneType has no attr findall` meaning your `table` or `row` variable is `None` and you are trying to  run `None.findall()`  Which obviously doesn't exist

Comment: You almost certainly meant to specify 'table' rather than 'tadle'. You should note also that there are two tables on that page that match your class criteria. Your code (once corrected) will find the first of those tables which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing is because of syntax error in previous line which says `tadle`. It should be `table`. That will get rid of the findall error. You may need to check the subsequent errors and fix based on need

Comment: That is not a syntax error

Comment: Redox ：Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you need to fix your element typo to `table`. Your code was looking for an element called `tadle` and was returning `None` to signal it was not found. When you then attempt to do use this value to do another `findAll()` call it gives you the error.

Usually it is a good idea to test the return to ensure that item you are looking for is present.

If you are trying to extract the whole table, you could make the following changes:

```py
import bs4 as bs
import pickle
import requests

def find_and_save_CSI_300():
    response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSI_300_Index')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    
    for tr in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        tickers.append([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.findAll('td')])
        
    with open("CSI_tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers, f)
    
    print(tickers)
    return tickers

find_and_save_CSI_300()
```

This would give you a list holding each row of values:

```
[['2005', '923.45', '', ''], ['2006', '2,041.05', '1,117.60', '121.02'], ['2007', '5,338.28', '3,297.23', '161.55'], ['2008', '1,817.72', '−3,520.56', '−65.95'], ['2009', '3,575.68', '1,757.96', '96.71'], ['2010', '3,128.26', '−447.42', '−12.51'], ['2011', '2,345.74', '−782.52', '−25.01'], ['2012', '2,522.95', '177.21', '7.55'], ['2013', '2,330.03', '−192.92', '−7.65'], ['2014', '3,533.71', '1,203.68', '51.66'], ['2015', '3,731.00', '197.29', '5.58'], ['2016', '3,310.08', '−420.92', '−11.28'], ['2017', '4,030.85', '720.77', '21.78'], ['2018', '3,010.65', '−1,020.20', '−25.31'], ['2019', '4,096.58', '1,085.93', '36.07'], ['2020', '5,211.29', '1,114.71', '27.21']]
```